# How can I fix C# DataGridView intermittent anchor problem?

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my app, I have two DataGridView controls. On my Windows development instance (11 Home in Fusion) and on three test instances (11 Home on VirtualBox 7, 11 Home on VirtualBox 6, and a Windows 11 computer), both DataGridView controls anchor correctly and resize with the form.

On at least two of my client's computers, one of the DataGridViews doesn't anchor. One of the client computers is VirtualBox 7 11 Home, don't know the other one.

This is what it looks like on all my computers and most of my clients':
[image: correct]

And here's what it looks like on the bad ones:
[image: incorrect]

As you can see, it just doesn't stretch to the edge, even though it is properly anchored and works on all my test systems and development machine, whether I am full screen or partial. If I maximize the app, the errant DataGridView will briefly show the narrower size as the main DGV displays with thousands of rows, but then it snaps to the edge. The problem client machines never snap.

On one of the machines, the rows in the errant DGV have bad font sizes as well.

Any ideas what's wrong here?

**EDIT** The top errant grid is in a GroupBox. I'm going to move it out of the group box and get the client to install the update, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: What is the screen size in pixels of the client machines ? Check the screen size vs the MaximumSize property of the control.

Comment: How and where do you make your datagridview control dock into its parent control? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Screen size doesn't seem to matter @Graffito - some are smaller, some are larger. All of them are smaller than my Thunderbolt Display. And resizing the window doesn't matter.

Comment: Both grid's anchors are set at design time @WolfgangRoth. And again, it works on all my test systems and most clients - only a few machines where it doesn't.

Comment: @WolfgangRoth I can't provide an example unless I could somehow get my clients to install a bunch of test apps until they were able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Graffito MaximumSize is empty - 0,0 - there is no max size value.

Comment: I suspect it's a problem with the GroupBox. The top errant grid is in a group box, the bottom behaving grid is not. I think that I can move it out of the group box and perhaps that will solve it.

Doesn't explain why it only happens on a few machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a tip from @Graffito about screen size, I guessed that the clients might be using the Display Scale feature of Windows.

Sure enough, I was able to reproduce the problem when I used it. So it's a problem with the GroupBox control and using Display Settings, Scale and Layout, and increase to greater than 100%.

Moving the grid out of the GroupBox fixed it.