# Picturebox changes position at runtime VS2019

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a picturebox that won't stay in position at runtime. This picturebox was to the left of a row of 3 buttons. I added a button to the right of the 3 buttons and now the picturebox moves rightward at runtime so it's superimposed over one of the buttons. The picturebox resides inside of a groupbox along with the buttons:

Designer:

[image: picturebox in designer]

Runtime:

[image: picturebox at runtime]

The label to the left of the picturebox has text of variable length, but even if I remove that label the result is still the same.

Suggestions?

Here is the layout code:

```
            // 
        // pictureBoxVSMStatus
        // 
        this.pictureBoxVSMStatus.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.pictureBoxVSMStatus.Image = global::Anesthesia.Properties.Resources.grey_led;
        this.pictureBoxVSMStatus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(325, 20);
        this.pictureBoxVSMStatus.Name = "pictureBoxVSMStatus";
        this.pictureBoxVSMStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(24, 24);
        this.pictureBoxVSMStatus.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
        this.pictureBoxVSMStatus.TabIndex = 241;
        this.pictureBoxVSMStatus.TabStop = false;
```

To Summarize:

-this pictureBox is contained in a groupBox
-it was working fine until I added another button on the far right and shifted the pictureBox and the (now) 4 buttons to the left

I'm happy to post another other code snippets you think are relevant

Comment: Nobody can help with just images. You need to simplify this and show enough code in your question to replicate the problem.

Comment: Looks like its position is relative to the orange label but without more detail like the code for the control layout we can't help.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75997090/10024425

Comment: HasanH- if you’ll reread my question, you’ll see that the picture box exhibits the same behavior even if I remove the orange label. I’ll post the layout code in a sec

Comment: GroupBoxes are only meant to be used to group radio button.  Problem like this occur when controls are place directly into the form.  Best solution is to replace your GroupBoxes with panels to separate the form into smaller pieces.

Comment: Thanks jdweng. I do believe that’s the problem